Issue in LibVlcSharp: resume play after invoking NextFrame multiple times is not smooth
I have a windows forms application based on .NET 8.0. I use LibVLCSharp 3.9.0 to display a video file saved in a samba shared folder.
This is my code to play the video file:
var libVLCOptions = new string[]
{
    "--no-osd",
    "--no-spu",
    "--avcodec-hw=any", // Enable hardware acceleration
    "--avcodec-hw=dxva2" // Use DirectX Video Acceleration (DXVA2) on Windows
};
var _libVLC = new LibVLC(libVLCOptions);

var _eventMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC);

string[] mediaOptions = {
   $":smb-user={user}",
   $":smb-pwd={password}",
   ":network-caching=3000", 
   ":sout-keep" 
};

// Create a new media instance
var media = new Media(_libVLC, new Uri(sambaPath), mediaOptions);

// Set the media to the media player
_eventMediaPlayer.Media = media;

var videoView = new VideoView { MediaPlayer = _eventMediaPlayer };
videoView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;            
EventsVideoPanel.Controls.Add(videoView);

// Play the media
_eventMediaPlayer.Play();

Above code works well and video is displayed without any issues.
I also have two buttons, one for resuming video playback and another for forwarding the video one frame at a time:
private void ResumeButton_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{           
   _eventMediaPlayer?.Play();
}

private void ForwardButton_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{          
   _eventMediaPlayer?.NextFrame();
}

When I click on the ForwardButton just once then video is paused. If I click the ResumeButton right after this, then video play resumes smoothly without any issue. But if I click on the ResumeButton several times, then video playback starts with skipping a lot of frames after the frame currently displayed.
So I click on ForwardButton e.g. 5 times. Video pauses and 5 consecutive frames are displayed ok. But when I click on ResumeButton right after this, a lot of frames are skipped and video playback is not smooth.
Any help on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

https://superuser.com/questions/1759971/vlc-how-to-continue-playback-regardless-of-how-close-from-start-or-end-i-was

@HansPassant I am facing the issue regardless of how close from start or end I am.

Sure.  VLC wants to start playback at a keyframe, that's your nemesis.
